# UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi

I want to use python3.4 in my project, but i was getting error:

*!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python34_plugin.so: undefined symbol: spool_request !!!*

I have the file in the dir, but it just don't working.

**uwsgi**

```
#mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /data/mysite/project
# Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file       = /data/mysite/project/mysite/wsgi.py
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /data/mysite/venv/pt3
# master
master          = True
plugins-dir     = /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
plugins         = python34
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 5
# the socket
socket          = /tmp/mysite.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
# account to start process
uid             = root
gid             = root
# Output messages to log
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
```

PS. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably used different uWSGI build profiles or source code versions to build your python plugin and uwsgi binary.

To fix that issue, clone source code of uWSGI version that you want to use and compile it and proper plugin:

```
make buildprofile
PYTHON=python3.4 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python34"
```

After doing that, stop all uWSGI servers in your system, replace uWSGI binary in your system with freshly build one, replace plugin for python 3.4 with fresh one and start uWSGI again.